# Before/After event stock price volatility regression

Tags: regression, stata, finance, volatility

So for my dissertation I need to discuss the impact of presidential campaigns on stock price volatility and I need some advice on which test or methodology to use? (not very sophisticated if possible).

Speaking with my supervisor, I know my independent variable will be the before/after of the launch date (0 for the 60 trading days preceding the launch; and 1 for the 30 days after the launch) and the dependent variable is the stock price volatility. I also have a couple control variables such as the number of employees of the companies as well as the revenues.

I already collected the data and started working on stata but I am unsure how to proceed. All suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: My advice is start working with the statistics consulting center or statistics department at your university.  To do this well, you will need a sophisticated analysis.  Something simple will not work for your dissertation.  For you to get good help on Cross Validated, it is better to ask a specific question than a general one.